# How to rewrite this haskell function using folds?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, higher-order-functions, fold, determinants

I wrote a haskell function to calculate the determinant of a matrix:

```
determinant :: Matrix -> Int
determinant [] = 0
determinant [[k]] = k
determinant n = sum [((-1) ^ m) * (head n !! m) * determinant (removeColumn (drop 1 n) m) | m <- [0 .. l]]
  where
    l = length (head n) - 1
```

It uses the helper function 'removeColumn' to extract the columns:

```
removeColumn :: Matrix -> Int -> Matrix
removeColumn m n = map (\row -> take (n-1) row ++ drop n row) m
```

I want to try to rewrite the '**determinant**' function using folds. I have been brainstorming for a while but I can't think of how to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want that? And in what way? It's easy enough to implement `sum` and `length` as folds, but presumably that's not what you had in mind? Also: note that explicitly calculating determinant isn't really something that's done in practical applications. The direct algorithms like the one you showed doesn't scale at all (exponential in the matrix size). In practice, if you needed a deteminant what you'd actually do is compute the eigenvalues and take their product. Cf. also [Down with Determinants!](https://www.axler.net/DwD.html)

Comment: @leftaroundabout Hi, thanks for responding. I'm learning Haskell for fun and I just wanted to see if the determinant function I have can be rewritten using folds as I'm trying to learn folds. I'm not too worried about industry practice as this is just for learning the concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to convert your version without changing it fundamentally, because it uses an irregular recursion scheme. For folds you would want your function to have a basic structure like this for some `z` and `k`:

```
determinant [] = z
determinant (x : xs) = k x (determinant xs)
```

Your functions recurses on `determinant (removeColumn (drop 1 n) m)`, so it is not obviously compatible.

Instead of starting with your function, I have taken the liberty to write an implementation based on [the Leibniz formula from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Leibniz_formula):

```
import Data.Bifunctor (first, bimap)

-- e.g. insertEverywhere 0 [1,2] == [(0,[0,1,2]),(1,[1,0,2]),(2,[1,2,0])]
-- the tupled integer keeps track of the number of inversions
insertEverywhere :: a -> [a] -> [(Int, [a])]
insertEverywhere x = 
  (\(ys,yss) -> (0,(x:ys)):yss) 
    . foldr 
      (\y (ys1,ys2) -> (y:ys1, (1, y:x:ys1):map (bimap (+ 1) (y:)) ys2))
      ([], [])

permutations :: [a] -> [(Int, [a])]
permutations = 
  foldr 
    (\x xs -> concatMap (\(n, xs) -> map (first (+ n)) (insertEverywhere x xs)) xs) 
    [(0, [])]

determinant :: Num a => [[a]] -> a
determinant = 
  sum 
    . map (\(i,p) -> (-1) ^ i * product (zipWith (!!) p [0..]))
    . perms
```

I'd say the essential part of this implementation is the use of the permutations as an intermediate structure (tupled with the number of inversions).